# Casting Object Types

Tags: java, casting

I'm a little confuse about casting object types. Given the example below:

```
public class Test() {

 public void method1() { System.out.println("Method 1");
 public void method2() { System.out.println("Method 2");
 }

public class Test1() extends Test{

  @Override public void method1() { System.out.println("Method 11");
  @Override public void method2() { System.out.println("Method 22");
   public void method 3() { System.out.println("Method 3");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test a = new Test1(); 
       a.method1(); //method invokes the overridden method1() of Test1, not Test the superclass
       a.method2(); //method invokes the overridden method2() of Test1, not Test the superclass
       a.method3(); //error, must cast == ((Test1)a).method3();
    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is when I invoked method1 & method2, the compiler or the JVM was able to invoke the method of the derived or subclass, so why does it still need to be downcasted/casted to invoke the method3()?

I tried overloading method1 and method2 of the superclass instead of overriding it; The compiler/JVM will require you to downcast the object reference variable before allowing you to invoke the overloaded methods. So, what this means is that without downcasting, you can only invoke the superclass's methods as well as the overridden methods defined in the subclass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your reference `a` is of type `Test`, but `method3` does not exist in `Test`.

```
Test a = new Test1();
// ^-reference   ^-object 
//   type          type
```

Rules:

- **Reference type** tells us what methods are visible.
- **Object type** tells us what implementations of the visible methods are considered.

---

This is one of the most basic examples I can think of:

```
public class Animal
{
     public void speak()
     {
          System.out.println("BLARGHGH");
     }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
     @Override
     public void speak()
     {
          System.out.println("Woof");
     }
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
     @Override 
     public void speak()
     {
          System.out.println("Meow");
     }

     public void throwUpFurball()
     {
          System.out.println("So fluffy!");
     }
}

public class Test()
{
     public static void main(final String args[])
     {
          Animal animal1 = new Animal(); 
          animal1.speak(); // BLARGHGH
          animal1.throwUpFurball(); // Compilation error - method not found. It will ask for casting

          Animal animal2 = new Cat();
          animal2.speak(); // Meow
          ((Cat)animal2).throwUpFurball(); // Must be cast, because throwUpFurball does not exist in Animal

          Animal animal3 = new Dog();
          animal3.speak(); // Woof
          ((Cat)animal3).throwUpFurball(); // Compiles, but throws ClassCastException at runtime, because the object type of animal3 is Dog

          Cat animal4 = new Cat();
          animal4.speak(); // Meow
          animal4.throwUpFurball(); // No casting necessary, because animal4 is of type Cat

          Object animal5 = new Animal();
          animal5.speak(); // Again, compilation problem. The type Object does not contain the speak() API, so it will require casting.
     }
}
```

Comment: The overridden method1() and method2() do not exist in Test, but why can I invoke them?

Comment: @Marz Because you added them to `Test` they are publicly available and the overridden methods will be called if you override them.

Comment: @Marz This is the problem with bad naming. It gets confusing when you ask and answer code questions. Of course `method1` and `method2` exist in `Test`. You've declared them yourself. Plus, that's the reason I've added those rules in the answer. In your case, the overridden implementations execute.

Comment: @GGrec: I'm sorry about the bad naming. I just made it all up without thinking on an actual situation, my bad. Anyway, you're saying that basically the compiler/JVM can invoke/reach all the methods of the subclass; it's just that they will only allow you to call the methods that are also defined/declared in the class declared as the reference type? Some sort of a rule or something?

Comment: @Marz `will only allow you to call the methods that are also defined/declared in the class declared as the reference type` Bingo. I've added an example to clarify. :-)

Comment: @GGrec: Thank you! I guess it is how inheritance works. I'm assuming that it is a rule to only allow you to invoke the methods defined/declared/visible in the Reference Type even if the compiler/JVM can call/reach the methods of the Object Type given that they are able to call/reach the overriding methods - the methods declared in the subclass/Object Type that overrides the original method. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Test1 a = new Test1();` - the references should be clear!

ps: close your methods with a }; just because... AND  method 3() should be method3()

:)

hope i understood you right!

```
public class Test1() extends Test{

  @Override public void method1() { System.out.println("Method 11");}
  @Override public void method2() { System.out.println("Method 22");}
   public void method3() { System.out.println("Method 3");}

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test1 a = new Test1(); 
       a.method1(); //method invokes the overridden method1() of Test1, not Test the superclass
       a.method2(); //method invokes the overridden method2() of Test1, not Test the superclass
       a.method3(); //error, must cast == ((Test1)a).method3();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put a closing }, and accidentally placed a space between method and 3. Anyway, I know how to make it run, I'm just confused how it really works. :D

Comment: haha i see :)  this is typical programming: it runs, but you don´t know why----OR there is a bug and you can´t find it hahaha